# How to convert xsd:dateTime literal into xsd:date in GraphDB?

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I am trying to convert xsd:dateTime into xsd:date to be able to FILTER objects only by dates.
But by doing following in GraphDB

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?s ?e { 
    VALUES (?start ?end) {("2011-02-02T14:45:14"^^xsd:dateTime "2011-02-04T14:45:13"^^xsd:dateTime)}
    BIND ( xsd:date(?start) AS ?s)
    BIND ( xsd:date(?end) AS ?e)
}
```

I get the following error

```
org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.QueryEvaluationException: Unknown function 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date'
```

But as one can see here [GraphDB Javascript Functions](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/javascript-functions.html)
there is a usage of xsd:date function.

Comment: I'm sure the documentation is just wrong here. According to standard SPARQL 1.1 this function does not exist: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#FunctionMapping And in the GraphDB docs the function is also not listed as extension: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/devhub/time-functions.html?highlight=function

Comment: But yes, I can reproduce the error while `xsd:dateTime` indeed works. So either the function is not there anymore in RDF4J or it was never. By the way, for Virtuoso it would work, so sometimes triple stores do support different additional features w.r.t. the standard

Comment: @AKSW thank you! Could you suggest any ways how to work it out is SPARQL? Or I need to create custom functions for GraphDB in that case, saying in [GraphDB Javascript Functions](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/javascript-functions.html)

Comment: well, yes. A custom Javascript function could do this for you I assume. I'm still not sure what kind of type a Javascript function will return. In the worst case, you could just return the date as a string and then call `BIND (STRDT(jsfn:date(?start), xsd:date) as ?s)`

Comment: other workaround: `bind(strdt(concat(str(year(?start)),"-",
                       str(month(?start)),"-",
                       str(day(?start))), xsd:date)
       as ?s)`

Comment: or `bind(strdt(SUBSTR(str(?start), 0, 11), xsd:date) as ?s)` - but I'm not really happy with both, the first omits leading zeros for year month and day, i.e. `2011-02-02` becomes `2011-2-2` which is (afaik) invalid. the second one might get into trouble with timezones if those occur

Answer (score 3):

The documentation from the link about GraphDB Javascript Functions uses an non-existing function `xsd:date`. For some reason it didn't end in the release.

Some technical notes.

The RDF values passed as arguments to the user defined javascript functions undergo a type conversion. The instances of `org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.IRI` and `org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.BNode` are passed "as-is", but the Literals are converted like:

- if it is an integer datatype e.g. one of (xsd:integer, xsd:long, xsd:int, xsd:byte, xsd:short, xsd:nonPositiveInteger, xsd:negativeInteger, xsd:nonNegativeInteger, xsd:positiveInteger, xsd:unsignedLong, xsd:unsignedInt, xsd:unsignedShort and xsd:unsignedByte) the value passed is a `long`
- if it is one of: xsd:decimal, xsd:float or xsd:double the value passed is a  `double`
- if it is one of: xsd:dateTime, xsd:date, xsd:time, xsd:gYearMonth, xsd:gMonthDay, xsd:gYear, xsd:gMonth or xsd:gDay the value passed is an instance of `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`
- if it is a duration, e.g. one of: xsd:duration, xsd:dayTimeDuration or xsd:yearMonthDuration the value passed is an instance of `javax.xml.datatype.Duration`
- finally, for xsd:boolean is a `boolean`
- for anything else, the Literal's label as `String`

Alternatively, the return value is also converted.
If it is an instance of `org.eclipse.rdf4j.Value`, no conversion is done.
Otherwise, conversion to RDF literal depends on its type and also on what is avaliable in RDF4J `ValueFactory` as `createLiteral` methods that can handle these, including the `XMLGregorianCalendar`. So if there is no specific handler, the string value of the result is used to create the Literal.

In the example from the first answer, the result of `jsfn:convertDate` is of type `jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeDate` so when the literal of the result is created, the plugin invokes its `toString` and that lead to results like `[Date 2011-02-02T14:45:14.000Z]`

Further, the scripting engine in the plugin is restricted to have access only to classes starting with `java.lang.` (excluding `java.lang.Thread`), `org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.` and `com.ontotext.trree.sdk.`

Having in mind the above notes and restrictions, a javascript function that converts a `xsd:dateTime` to `xsd:date` need to set the fields of the calendar value which are related to the time to `DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED` which is actually `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and construct a Literal through the RDF4J `ValueFactory`:

```
PREFIX jsfn:<http://www.ontotext.com/js#>
INSERT DATA {
    [] jsfn:register '''
    function convertDate(value) {
        value.setTime(java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE, java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE, java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        return org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.impl.SimpleValueFactory.getInstance().createLiteral(value);
    }
'''
}
```

HTH

Comment: Interesting. Clearly none of those details can be found in the documentation, so only a GraphDB dev like you could write custom Javascript functions that return typed literals or similar things beyond plain strings.

Answer (score 1):

Create javascript function in GraphDB like:

```
PREFIX jsfn:<http://www.ontotext.com/js#>
INSERT DATA {
    [] jsfn:register '''
    function convertDate(value) {
        return new Date(value);
    }
'''
}
```

Verify that the function is registered or:

```
PREFIX jsfn:<http://www.ontotext.com/js#>
SELECT ?s ?o {
    ?s jsfn:enum ?o
}
```

And then use it  as follows:

```
PREFIX jsfn:<http://www.ontotext.com/js#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?s ?e { 
    VALUES (?start ?end) {("2011-02-02T14:45:14"^^xsd:dateTime "2011-02-04T14:45:13"^^xsd:dateTime)}
    BIND ( jsfn:convertDate(?start) AS ?s)
    BIND ( jsfn:convertDate(?end) AS ?e)
}
```

Returned result is:

[Date 2011-02-02T14:45:14.000Z]

[Date 2011-02-04T14:45:13.000Z]

Hope this helps.

Comment: well, `[Date 2011-02-02T14:45:14.000Z]` would not be a date, right? As far as I understand, the returned literal should be `"2011-02-02"^^xsd:date`