# What is the Javascript class of IRI or blank node parameters received by a JS function in GraphDB

Tags: javascript, graphdb

In GraphDB, if I register a javascript function f in GraphDB with

```
prefix extfn:<http://www.ontotext.com/js#>
INSERT DATA {
    [] <http://www.ontotext.com/js#register> '''
        function f(x) { ... }
      '''
```

What will be the class of x if f is called with an IRI or blank node as argument, i.e. not a String? The method invokation `x.constructor` yields `undefined`so it's difficult to figure out what's its type.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: some details are avaliable as answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216278/how-to-convert-xsddatetime-literal-into-xsddate-in-graphdb
HTH

Comment: @Damyan Thanks. Indeed, the answer is  there ... and apparently nowhere in the GraphDB documentation.